# Does replica.lag.time.max.ms cause message loss?

Tags: apache-kafka

Will the replica.lag.time.max.ms configuration in kafka not lose messages? The default value of this configuration is 10 seconds. Assuming that the follower does not initiate a request to the leader within 8 seconds, it will not be kicked out of the ISR. At this time, the leader fails and the follower is promoted to the leader, which will result in the loss of 8 seconds of messages. If a message is lost, how to ensure that the message is not lost? By setting ack=all and setting min.insync.replicas greater than 1?

How to configure to ensure that kafka messages are not lost